# determining device storage space not working: android

Tags: java, android, storage

I am using the following code to determine the storage space AVAILABLE on my device when I install or delete apps, and **I am not getting the correct space available printed in my monitor**. This code gets run in a Broadcast Receiver that is listening for when apps are removed or installed.

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() *(long)stat.getAvailableBlocks();
long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / 1048576;
System.out.println("Megs Available :"+megAvailable);
```

**when I tested this code here are the results I got:**

I started with 12437MB (Let's just say 37MB, since this is the only number that will change).

I ADDED AN APP that was 1MB... 37 MB available went up to 41 MB available (should have decreased)

I ADDED AN APP that was 12MB... 41 MB available went down to 15 MB available (decreased too much)

I ADDED AN APP that was about 1 MB... 15 MB available went down to 14MB (maybe this one worked correctly)

I then DELETED an app that was 1MB... 14MB available stayed at 14MB available

I DELETED an app that was 2 MB... 14MB stayed at 14MB

I DELETED an app that was 1MB... 14MB available went up to 19MB available

I DELETED an app that was 12MB.. 19 MB available stayed at 19MB...

After doing this test I tried adding a 5 second delay between when I delete or install and app and when I get the device storage space, but the numbers were still not correct.

In addition to this, my total available space according to my program is always about 12.4 GB, and my phone settings says I have 12.1 GB... Is the phone settings more accurate than my program?

**Is there a way to get more accurate numbers? or is this method just not very reliable? or the cache data on the phone is making the numbers unreliable?**

Answer (score 2):

The code you're using is deprecated for Android API 9 or above. There's how you should calculate available storage space:

Use getExternalFilesDirs method (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getExternalFilesDirs(android.content.Context, java.lang.String)) to get a path to external storage directory:

```
File[] externalStoragesPaths = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(getActivity(), null);
```

This method is a member of ContextCompat class (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html), which provides compatibility for all Context class features since API 4.
The first path returned from getExternalFilesDirs will be the absolute path of the external storage where the application can place persistent files it owns:

```
if(externalStoragesPaths != null) {
    File externalStoragePath = externalStoragesPaths[0]; 
}
```

Then you can determine available storage space:

API 9 - API 17:

```
long availableSpace = externalStoragePath.getFreeSpace(); // available space in bytes
```

API 18 and above:

```
long availableSpace = new StatFs(externalStoragePath.getPath()).getAvailableBytes();
```

You can also try to use getUsableSpace() method (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getUsableSpace%28%29) or getAvailableBlocksLong() and getBlockSizeLong() method instead of getAvailableBlocks() and getBlockSize().

Comment: Did you mean to do "externalStoragesPaths.getFreeSpace()" for API 9-17, and "externalStoragesPaths.getPath()" for API 18 and above? Or you meant to use "file"?

Comment: Check out my edited answer, now I made it more correct and clear.

Comment: This method is giving me the same result as the method I posted in my question... maybe it's just not possible to get the MB storage value that accurate each time one app is downloaded or deleted?

Comment: Try to use methods that I added to my answer. Also, you can try to use getFreeSpace() method from StatFs and compare it to other approaches.